# Слияние файлов через cmd

Tags: cmd, bat, git-cmd

Перевожу игру на русский. Необходима помощь по консоли.
Задача стоит в том, чтобы склеить файлы формата *.scenarygame из множества разных подпапок (которые суть ни что иное как строки диалога, которые можно открыть блокнотом) в один тхт файл.

Команда for %f in (*.scenarygame) do type "%f" >> output.txt работает только для конкретной папки, но не для подпапок. А их десятки.

Ось вин7 64х.

Comment: Для обработки файлов (в том числе рекурсивно) есть специальная команда **forfiles**

Comment: А можно пример кода? Я в кодинг не могу..

Comment: В консоли пишете **forfiles /?** и в ответ выводится справка на языке локальной версии. Там же в конце приведены примеры использования команды.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b /s /a:-d *.scenarygame') do type "%x">>output.txt
```

> Fabio > Не удается найти указанный файл

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b /s /a:-d X:\folder\*.scenarygame') do type "%x">>Y:\folder\output.txt
```

Comment: Не удается найти указанный файл пишет :(

Comment: Пример ошибки: "каталог откуда вызываю консоль" >type  1>>output.txt

Comment: @Fabio *Не удается найти указанный файл* Укажите полные пути - и в шаблоне, и для файла результата.

Comment: Судя по коду все правильно, но не работает. Все равно не удается найти указанный файл. Может у меня ось такая... Все равно спасибо за помощь